# $Y$ topological subspace of $X$. If some subset $C\subset Y$ is compact, does this mean it's compact in $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Say that $X$ is topological space and that $Y$ is some subspace.  If I have a set $C\subset Y$, then is it okay to say that "$C$ is compact" or must I say where it is compact, i.e. "$C$ is compact in Y", and furthermore, if $C$ is compact in $Y$ then I suppose that implies it must be compact in $X$? I know that for some set $U\subset Y$, if $U$ is open we need to say where it's open, like $U$ is open in $Y$ or $X$, but a friend mentioned that for compactness this doesn't matter.

Comment: $C\subseteq Y$ is compact with respect to $Y$ *iff* it's compact with respect to $X$, so it doesn't matter. (See Tim R's answer for details.)

Comment: Compactness is a property of spaces, so the only issue is that a subspace of a subspace is a subspace.

Comment: For real ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $C$ is compact in $Y$.  Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be a an open cover of $C$ with respect to $X$.  Then $\{U_\alpha\cap Y\}$ is an open cover of $C$ with respect to $Y$. Then it  has a finite subcover $\{U_1\cap Y,\ldots, U_n\cap Y\}$.  Hence $\{U_1,\ldots, U_n\}$ is an open subcover of $\{U_\alpha\}$ and $C$ is compact with respect to $X$.  If $C$ is compact with respect to $X$ a similar argument shows it is also compact with repect to $Y$. So, one can simply say that $C$ is compact.